# how do I reset img to original image after user goes idle

Tags: javascript

So far this is what I have tried. I cant seem to figure out how to reset the img src to the first image in the folder after the user does not click on a button for 5 seconds.
HTML

```
<div class="slider">
          <div class="img-box">
            <img src="images/a.jpg" class="slider-img">
          </div>
    
          <button id="first" class="btn" onclick="prev()">Prev</button>
          <button id="second" class="btn" onclick="next()">Next</button>
        </div>
```

JavaScript

```
var slider_img = document.querySelector('.slider-img');
var images = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg', 'd.jpg', 'e.jpg'];
var i = 0;

function prev(){
    if(i <= 0) i = images.length;   
    i--;
    return setImg();             
}

function next(){
    if(i >= images.length-1) i = -1;
    i++;
    return setImg();             
}

function setImg(){
    return slider_img.setAttribute('src', "images/"+images[i]);
    
}


var btnDwn = document.onmousedown
function idk(){
    return slider_img.setAttribute('src', "images/"+images[0]);
}
if(btnDwn == false){
    setInterval(idk(),5000)
}
```

Comment: I know this isn't the problem but your returns are not correct nor are they actually being used, you can get rid of them. Also, for setInterval, you will want to get rid of the `()` so it just says `setInterval(idk,5000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll define "inactivity/idleness" to if user stops moving mouse AND stops clicking

I do this by making a function that every time you call it, a timeout is set(and the previous timeout deleted) so that the content INSIDE the timeout **ONLY** activates **AFTER** 5 seconds of **NOT BEING TRIGGERED**

Do note that to be idle, stop using your mouse and do not click the functions for about 5 seconds and see it in action :D

```
var slider_img = document.querySelector('.slider-img');
var images = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg', 'd.jpg', 'e.jpg'];
var i = 0; var timeout=0;

function prev(){
    if(i <= 0) i = images.length;   
    i--; resetImg();
    return setImg();             
}

function next(){
    if(i >= images.length-1) i = -1;
    i++; resetImg();
    return setImg();             
}

function setImg(){
    return slider_img.setAttribute('src', "images/"+images[i]);
}

function resetImg(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout=setTimeout(()=>{slider_img.setAttribute('src', "images/"+images[0]);},5000);
}

//every time you click those buttons, you are 'active', now being active would also count as moving your mouse
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',resetImg)
```